# How to run Invoke-Command in chunks?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I want to run `Invoke-Command` on hundreds of servers. It chokes when trying to run them asynchronously, so I want to run them in chunks.

How can I tell powershell to launch only X servers in each go?

Answer (score 0):

The `ThrottleLimit` switch can be passed.

From the docs:

> -ThrottleLimit int
>          The maximum number of concurrent connections that can be established to run this command.
>          If you omit this parameter or enter a value of 0, the default value, 32, is used.